# WPF C# Drag & Drop Events

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a canvas that I drop some tools onto to create a diagram (this resides in tabitem2).

What I'm looking to do is when a tool is dropped on the canvas is associate an event that spits out text to a textbox (located in tabitem3).

XAML:

```
<ListBox>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DragImage"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Image Source="toolitem1.png"></Image>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
 <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" AllowDrop="True" Background="Aqua" Drop="DropImage"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void DragImage(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Image image = e.Source as Image;
        DataObject data = new DataObject(typeof(ImageSource), image.Source);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(image, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);

    }


    private void DropImage(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageSource image = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageSource)) as ImageSource;
        Image imageControl = new Image() { Width = image.Width, Height = image.Height, Source = image };
        Canvas.SetLeft(imageControl, e.GetPosition(this.Canvas).X);
        Canvas.SetTop(imageControl, e.GetPosition(this.Canvas).Y);
        this.Canvas.Children.Add(imageControl);
}
```

UPDATE:

Added some sample code and tried the suggestions from the folks below to no avail. It looks like when I try to use DragDrop.Drop in my ListBoxItem object it will override the DropImage event for my canvas so I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the [drop event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.drop.aspx)?
basiclly, in .net/wpf 4, there is a DragDrop class to help with these matters. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.aspx) is the MSDN documentation on the matter.

[EDIT]

From what I am seeing, you are dragging/dropping an image.  I think what you need to do is, instead, make some custom object that holds your image AND some data.  if you make the image a dependency property, you can bind to that in your listbox item, and then in  your drop event, access the other properties in order to get the data that you want.

Comment: yes, i have. i'm unable to get unique drop events for each item. for example, i want tool#1 when dropped to canvas spit out "test" on my textbox. if i drop tool#2 i want it to spit out "yaddayadda". edited my question with some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

there is only one event for each drop target. whatever source-related info you want to leverage in that handler should be passed as part of the data parameter to DoDragDrop

Answer (score -1):

I think [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx) article will help you. There are [part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part2.aspx) and [part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part3.aspx) as well.

Good luck

Comment: This only describes DragDrop when the drag source is in the application and there is no intention to provide or consume data to or from other applications. There should be a simpler way, seems like one’s supposed to somehow use `PreviewDragOver` and `PreviewDrop` somehow.